# Search using TextFiled in Multi Sectioned TableView - Swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, search, multidimensional-array

I made a search with textfield with the below method and its working fine when i use single section in table view.

But i don’t know how to achieve this when i have multiple sections in table View

**In Normal Single Sectioned tableview**

```
foodTypeArr = ["Japanesh", "Chinesh", "Lebanesh", "Italian", "Indian"]
searchResultArr.addObjects(from: foodTypeArr as! [Any])

func searchAutocompleteEntriesWithSubstring(substring: String)
{
 searchResultArr.removeAllObjects()

        for curString in foodTypeArr
        {
            let myString:NSString! = curString as! NSString

            if (myString).lowercased.contains(substring)
            {
                searchResultArr.add(curString)
            }
        }

        self.tblList.reloadData()
 }
```

**In Multi Section TableView**

```
var searchAreaArr = NSMutableArray()    
var areaArr = [[String]]()
var areaTitles = NSArray()

areaArr = [["Vadvalli", "Mullai Nagar", "P.N.Pudhur"], ["Lawly Road", "Kowly Brown", "D.B Road"], ["Raja Street", "Gandhipark", "Five corner road”, "Main Town Hall”]]

areaTitles = ["Vadavalli", "R.S.Puram", "Town Hall"]

for i in 0..<areaArr.count
{
   searchAreaArr.addObjects(from: areaArr[i])
}
```

I’m calling the below method in TextField-shouldChangeCharactersIn range

```
func searchAutocompleteEntriesWithSubstring(substring: String)
{
    areaArr.removeAll()
            var mArr = [String]()

        for curString in searchAreaArr
        {
            let myString:NSString! = curString as! NSString

            if (myString).lowercased.contains(substring)
            {
                mArr.append(curString as! String)
            }
        }
        areaArr.insert(mArr, at: 0)
}
```

with this it is inserting the filtered Strings in the **0th array Index** in **areaArr**. But I need it should be on their sections and the section name should be their own, and to change the section Index of the filtered sections of strings

Say For example if the search text is **road**, it should be

```
R.S puram (Section 1)
- Lawly Road
- D.B Road
Town Hall (Section 2)
- Five corner road
```

My tableview Methods

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int
{
    return areaArr.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    return areaArr[section].count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String?
{
    if section < areaTitles.count
        {
            return areaTitles[section] as? String
        }
    return nil
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
        let cell:UITableViewCell = 
self.tblList.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as UITableViewCell!
    cell.textLabel?.text = "\(areaArr[indexPath.section][indexPath.row])"
}
```

I Lost my One whole day with it, Please Help to Fix this…. Your Suggestions are welcomed

Comment: add your proper json data so that we can guide you better.., your format is not clear currently..

Comment: @Er.Khatri Im Doing UI So im Doing with the static Content, you can also suggest to save and retrieve the values of areaArr....

Comment: At first I would recommend to store your data in a touple array to make your further job easier, like: var items = [(section: String, elements: [String])]()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this in shouldChangeCharactersIn method

```
let areaArr = [["Vadvalli", "Mullai Nagar", "P.N.Pudhur"], ["Lawly Road", "Kowly Brown", "D.B Road"], ["Raja Street", "Gandhipark", "Five corner road", "Main Town Hall"]]

let areaTitles = ["Vadavalli", "R.S.Puram", "Town Hall"]
let searchText = "road"
var areaArrResult = areaArr.map { $0.filter({ $0.lowercased().contains(searchText) }) }
let areaTitlesResult = areaTitles.filter {  !areaArrResult[areaTitles.index(of: $0)!].isEmpty }
areaArrResult = areaArrResult.filter { !$0.isEmpty }

print(areaArrResult)//[["Lawly Road", "D.B Road"], ["Five corner road"]]
print(areaTitlesResult)//["R.S.Puram", "Town Hall"]
```

**OR**

```
     var allDetails:[(String,[String])] = [] 
     var searchResult:[(String,[String])] = []


    allDetails = [("Vadavalli",["Vadvalli", "Mullai Nagar", "P.N.Pudhur"]),
                  ("R.S.Puram",["Lawly Road", "Kowly Brown", "D.B Road"]),
                  ("Town Hall",["Raja Street", "Gandhipark", "Five corner road", "Main Town Hall"])]
    searchAreaArr = areaArr.map({ ($0.0,$0.1.filter({ $0.lowercased().contains(substring) })) }).filter { !$0.1.isEmpty}
    print(searchResult)//[("R.S.Puram", ["Lawly Road", "D.B Road"]), ("Town Hall", ["Five corner road"])]
```

Then 
In `numberOfSections` `return searchResult.count`

In `numberOfRowsInScetion` `return searchResult[section].1.count`

In titleForHeaderInSection method you can use

```
return searchResult[section].0
```

In cellForRowAt method

`cell.textLabel?.text = "\(searchResult[indexPath.section].1[indexPath.row])"`

Comment: Thanks for your response.. im getting fatal error: Index out of range in areaTitleResult line

Comment: @AbiramiBala make sure count of areaTitles and count of areaArr are same.

Comment: Yes both count are same

Comment: what is allDetails - NSMutableDictionary () ...?

Comment: @AbiramiBala it is array of tuples. Check this [link](https://whatilearnedtoday.io/swift-tuples/)

Comment: searchAreaArr = areaArr.map({ (areaTitle:$0.0,areas:$0.1.filter({ $0.lowercased().contains(substring) })) }).filter { !$0.1.isEmpty} 
Its not clear to me that how this is working... but great....Thanks

Comment: How Can I get the selected cell index to change its background color.....?

Comment: `let selctedView = UIView()
   selctedView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
   cell?.selectedBackgroundView = selctedView`
you can use this in cellForRowAt method

Comment: var index = idexPath(),   index = indexPath (in didSelectRowAt) and if index == indexPath
            {  print ("Selected Cell")  } in cellForRowAt worked for me.... anyway thanks for your response